# Adding custom slots in QT4

Tags: qt

In Qt5 i used this method to connect the signals emitted by the process with the slot but this doesn't works with Qt4

```
connect(process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [=]{
ui->textBrowser->append(process->readAllStandardOutput());
});
```

As suggested by someone I tried to implement it this way replaced the original line by this

```
connect(process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), receiver, SLOT(yourCustomSlot()) );
```

and added this in mainwindow.h

```
class MyReceiverClass {

slots:
    void yourCustomSlot() {
        ui->textBrowser->append(process->readAllStandardOutput());
    }
};
```

But it didn't worked that way got declaration errors. I don't know what's the correct way to add a custom slot. Can somebody explain me how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not `slots` but `private slots` or `public slots`, based on what you want to achieve.

And you were using lambdas in you first example, that Qt5 support, but not Qt4 (as it uses older C++ standard).

And you need to have Q_OBJECT macros, if you want to use signals\slots mechanism in your class.

So your example would look like (header file):

```
#include <QObject>
class MyReceiverClass : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void yourCustomSlot() {
        ui->textBrowser->append(process->readAllStandardOutput());
    }
};
```

More about slots: [Qt4: Signals & Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html)

But looks like you refer to `ui` and `process` elements that are not existsing in your implementation of `MyReceiverClass`. You should make an ui form that contains textBrowser element and init it as gui for your widget. Something like this:

**// widget.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class QPushButton;

class MyReceiverClass  : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyReceiverClass (QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyReceiverClass ();

public slots:
    void yourCustomSlot() {
                ui->textBrowser->append(process->readAllStandardOutput());
            }

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**// widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
}
```

But you should really read docs on how to create widgets and gui based on UI-forms in Qt and also about slot&signals connectivity as your question shows a lack of understanding in how those fundamental mechanism works in Qt.

Comment: No i am not using any lambda now, and i tried to implement it this way but got error saying that
'ui' was not declared in this scope
'process' was not declared in this scope